# Linux network interface broadcast statistics

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ethernet

I am looking for a way to see the number of Ethernet broadcast frames transmit/received by the network interfaces.
I am familiar with many Linux commands,procs and options to get interface statistics (ifconfig , nstat (which shows ip broadcasts), /proc/net/dev , ifstat etc...).
For example /proc/net/dev shows received Multicast, but there is no reference for broadcasts.
Is there a standard way to see it ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try `ethtool`:

```
ethtool -S <NIC name>
```

But not all of drivers is support for statistic, read manpage of ethtool for more details.

**Updated**

The solution is looking at `/proc/net/netstat`, but it is not in human readable. Using some `awk` to manipulate it:

```
cat /proc/net/netstat | \ 
awk '(f==0) { i=1; while ( i<NF) {n[i] = $i; i++ }; f=1; next} \ 
(f==1){ i=1; while ( i<NF){ printf "%s = %d\n", n[i], $i; i++}; f=0}' | \ 
grep Bcast
```

Output in my machine:

```
InBcastPkts = 171
OutBcastPkts = 17
InBcastOctets = 11856
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but there are no broadcasts counter.

Comment: Do you see any line contain `tx_broadcast` or `rx_broadcast`

Comment: No, I don't, maybe it is related to interface driver ?

Comment: So I looked at my driver code, I see it doesn't count broadcasts. but is there other Linux generic interface for network stats (including broadcasts) ?

Comment: Thanks! Looks good (sorry I can't vote up-need 15 rep for that :))

Comment: Well, checking it looks like IP layer broadcast statistics, I don't think it consist Ethernet broadcast (such as ARP). I see that this proc is updated from the net/ipv4/proc.c file (which is following RFC4293 (MIB for IP))...